# Yii2 listview pagination position

Tags: listview, pagination, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want listview show pagination at bottom of the list but it appears at
top of the list here is my code when I want to render listview:

```
'layout' => "{pager}\n{summary}\n{items}\n",
```

also, I change pager like this : `'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}",` but it shows at left side.

Comment: The default position of the pagination is at the bottom of the list.
You don't have to set the layout parameter at all.

Comment: @tsanchev when don't set layout parameter again it's shown at left side

Comment: you might have some css classes applied to the list view that is causing it

Comment: @Mehran if you want pagination on the right you can do something like 'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}\n<div style=\"float: right;\">{pager}</div>"

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yeah I think you are right

Comment: just keep the default css that comes with yii and disable other assets or css files and see if the listview displays properly otherwise it could be due to a missing closing tag in you html

Answer (score 0):

you can disable pagination first at model search

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query'      => SomeModelClass::find(),
    'pagination' => false,
]);
```

your controller is like

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $query = Article::find()->where(['status' => 1]);
    $countQuery = clone $query;
    $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count()]);
    $models = $query->offset($pages->offset)
        ->limit($pages->limit)
        ->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
         'models' => $models,
         'pages' => $pages,
    ]);
}
```

and add pagination manually on top

```
echo LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pages,
]);
```

Comment: this in no way addresses the problem that is being faced by the OP